# Googlebot only seems to crawl my front page even when provided a different URL

Tags: seo, google-search, javascript

I'm new to the webmaster world and trying to get my site SEO ready.
It runs on javascript (AngularJS) and I set up all the things you'd need so that crawlers can read the site. I have the `<meta name="fragment" content="!">` tag and also set up the hashbang so it knows where to put the "escaped_fragment" part and read my javascript.

Currently, in my Google search console, I can fetch and render the front 
page of my site properly but anytime I add other fragments to test out that Google can read those, it only goes back and grabs the frontpage content.

Does anyone know how to make it so Google reads my other pages?

Comment: I look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17178466/is-including-meta-name-fragment-content-harmful-for-pages-with-hashbang and it seems google crawls different URLs when you use that meta tag. Does it work better if you take out that meta tag?

Comment: If you review the Google Search Console data for the last month (indexed pages, landing pages, search queries, content keywords), does it seem Google is crawling the site correctly or not?

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html which Google published in October 2015 the AJAX crawling standard has been depreciated. As long as you are not blocking the Googlebot from crawling your CSS and Javascript files then the Googlebot will be able to interpret what your AJAX content is and will be able to crawl it as if it where normal static content without needing to do anything special to the URL with hash fragments.